# How can object == this, but object.member != this.member in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an object, let's call it `o`, and a reference to `o`.

Within the scope of `o`, I set a member, let's call it `m`.

So in o, I call:

```
o.m = "blah"
```

Outside of o, I access `m`:

```
console.log(o.m)
```

Which gives me something that isn't "blah". I did:

```
console.log(this == this.parent.o)
```

which returns true. How is this possible? I'm using Chrome 17.0.963.56 m

**EDIT**

Also, I've tried within object `o`:

```
this.m = "blah"
console.log(this.m) // prints "blah"
```

but after exiting that scope and do:

```
console.log(o.m)
```

it prints something different.

Relevant code (see this.addEvent("playPauseButtonClicked")):

```
    // Controller code (singleton)
    function controller() {
        if (window.c) { return window.c; }
        window.c = this;
    ...
        // Event handling
        this.addEvent = function(eventName, callback) {
            if (!this.events[eventName]) this.events[eventName] = [];

            this.events[eventName].push(callback);
        }
        this.raiseEvent = function(eventName) {
            self = getController();
            if (self.events[eventName]) {
                var callbacks = self.events[eventName];
                var i = 0;
                for (i = 0; i<callbacks.length; ++i) {
                    callbacks[i]();
                }
            }
        }

        this.musicplayer = new zeitgeistPlayer(this, this.songStatus);
    ...
        this.addEvent("playPauseButtonClicked", function() {
            var controller = getController();
            var musicplayer = controller.musicplayer;
            switch (musicplayer.state) {
                case "paused":
                    musicplayer.resume();
                    controller.view.setButtonProperty("playPauseButton", "pause", true);
                    break;
                case "playing":
                    musicplayer.pause();
                    controller.view.setButtonProperty("playPauseButton", "pause", false);
                    break;
                case "stopped":
                    controller.playSong();
                    controller.view.setButtonProperty("playPauseButton", "pause", true);
                    break;
            }
        });

        if (this.playQueue.length == 0) this.view.setButtonProperty("playPauseButton", "disabled", true);

        this.raiseEvent("controllerLoaded");
    }

    // Functional classes
    function basePlayer(songStatus) {
        this.state = "stopped";    // states are: stopped, playing, paused
    ...
    }

    // implementation of basePlayer using the zeitgeist flash player
    function zeitgeistPlayer(controller, songStatus) {
        $.extend(this, new basePlayer(songStatus));
    ...
        this.controller = controller;

    ...

        this.pause = function () {
            if (this.controller.debug) console.log("player pausing");
            this.state = "paused";
            this.swf.pauseSong();
            if (this.controller.debug) console.log("player "+this.state);
            console.log(this);
            console.log(getController().musicplayer);
            console.log(this==getController().musicplayer);
        }
    ...
    }
```

Comment: I could give you an answer if your question was phrased better with a realistic test case. In so far, `var a = {a:'h'}, b = {a:'h'}; console.log(a.a==b.a);` returns true to me.

Comment: You have to initialize the variable. `var o = new obj; console.log(o.m);`

Comment: `p.changeState();` There is no `p` variable. What is your *actual* code?

Comment: What happened to the code you **just posted**?!?!  I wrote a long answer based on that, and now you've got something completely different up there

Comment: Relic just asked for the real code! I realize that this.p != (locally scoped) p. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

If you're inside of `o`, and you want to set `m`, you would say:

```
this.m = "blah";
```

it's possible that inside `o`, `o` is scoped to be something else, which is why things are not behaving as expected.

---

**EDIT 2** -- it looks like OP just changed his question, so the code below probably isn't relevant anymore -- *sigh*

---

**EDIT**

It looks like there are a few problems.  For one:

```
this.p = new player();
```

Where your player constructor looks like

```
function player(controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
```

You're not passing anything in for controller, which is why you're getting the error about undefined `p`.  Try this:

```
this.p = new player(this);
```

---

Also, in your controller constructor, once you define `p` to be a property of the return object—`this.p = new player(this)`—you need to refer to it as `this.p` from then on; `p` by itself is undeclared.  So

```
function controller() {
    this.p = new player(this);
    p.changeState();
    console.log(p.state);
```

needs to be

```
function controller() {
    this.p = new player(this);
    this.p.changeState();
    console.log(this.p.state);
```

Comment: @dookehster - I see your edit, but can you please post your entire definition of `o`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the variable.

`var x = new o;
console.log(o.m);`

Comment: Huh?! If the (weaker) equal operator failed, what makes you think the (stricter) identity operator will work?

Comment: because he wants it to return false... maybe I'm missing what he's actually trying to do here and what his actual question is...

Answer (score 0):

I'd change

```
this.p = new player();
p.changeState();
console.log(p.state);
```

to

```
this.p = new player(this);
this.p.changeState();
console.log(this.p.state);
```

Two changes:

1. `p` doesn't exist as a local variable in that context -- you need to use `this.p`
2. the player constructor needs a controller reference